# most pythonic way to transform dataframe into nested custom dict with tuple-style keys out of two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        "color": ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "green", "green", "green", "green"],
        "object": ["hat", "hat", "coat", "coat", "hat", "hat", "coat", "coat"],
        "group": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
        "value": [1.2 , 3.5, 5.4, 7.1, 6.4, 1.8, 3.5, 5.6]
    })
```

that looks like this:

[image]

I want to create a nested dict, with the columns "color" and "object" as the first key as a string (e.g. `"(blue, hat)"` (**Note:** This is a syntactically incorrect tuple with intention. It should be in string format!), the group as the key in the second level and the value as the key of the second level. I.e. my desired output is:

```
{
    "(blue, hat)": {
        1: 1.2,
        2: 3.5
    },
    "(blue, coat)": {
        1: 5.4,
        2: 7.1
    },
    "(green, hat)": {
        1: 6.4,
        2: 1.8
    },
    "(green, coat)": {
        1: 3.5,
        2: 5.6
    }
}
```

My approach would be to loop through the unique values of `color`, `object` and `group`, but that seems cumbersome to me. Is there a more pythonic approach?

Comment: A quite pythonic is to try *something* first.

Comment: Found my approach quite cumbersome (added in edit), therefore I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension with [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), if need tuples rept like strings use:

```
d = {str(k): v.set_index('group')['value'].to_dict() 
              for k, v in df.groupby(['color','object'])}
print (d)

  {
    "('blue', 'coat')": {
        1: 5.4,
        2: 7.1
    },
    "('blue', 'hat')": {
        1: 1.2,
        2: 3.5
    },
    "('green', 'coat')": {
        1: 3.5,
        2: 5.6
    },
    "('green', 'hat')": {
        1: 6.4,
        2: 1.8
    }
```

Or if need change format like `'tuple'`s without `''` use `f-string`s:

```
d = {f'({k[0]}, {k[1]})': v.set_index('group')['value'].to_dict() 
                 for k, v in df.groupby(['color','object'])}
```

Alternative with `join`:

```
d = {f'({", ".join(k)})': v.set_index('group')['value'].to_dict() 
                 for k, v in df.groupby(['color','object'])}
```

---

```
print (d)

{
    '(blue, coat)': {
        1: 5.4,
        2: 7.1
    },
    '(blue, hat)': {
        1: 1.2,
        2: 3.5
    },
    '(green, coat)': {
        1: 3.5,
        2: 5.6
    },
    '(green, hat)': {
        1: 6.4,
        2: 1.8
    }
}
```

Comment: Second one is solved it for me, thx! The output of the first one is wrong though (' ' around `color` values)